# hide Navigation Bar only on first page - Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, ios13

My app running on Swift UI, and my main page is `Home()`, In the home page there is `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink(destination: SaveThePlanet())`, I have hide the Navigation View on the main page "Home", its also hide in `SaveThePlanet()`.
How can I unhide the navigation back button in the `SaveThePlanet()` page?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {

    @State var show = false
    @State var showSaveThePlanet = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray
                ContentView()
                    .blur(radius: show ? 10 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(show ? 0.90 : 1)
                    .blur(radius: showSaveThePlanet ? 10 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(showSaveThePlanet ? 0.90 : 1)
                    .animation(.default)

                leftIcon(show: $show)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: showSaveThePlanet ? 300 : 70)
                    .scaleEffect(show ? 0.90 : 1)
                    .blur(radius: show ? 10 : 0)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)

                SaveThePlanet()
                    .background(Color("Bg"))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(color: Color("Green-Sh"), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                    .animation(.spring())
                    .offset(y: showSaveThePlanet ? 120 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                    .padding()

                rightIcon(show: $showSaveThePlanet)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 70)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                    .scaleEffect(show ? 0.90 : 1)
                    .blur(radius: show ? 10 : 0)
                    .opacity(showSaveThePlanet ? 0 : 1)


                rightIconClose(show: $showSaveThePlanet)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 70)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                    .scaleEffect(show ? 0.90 : 1)
                    .blur(radius: show ? 10 : 0)
                    .opacity(showSaveThePlanet ? 1 : 0)

                MenuView(show: $show)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include some code defining what leftIcon(:), rightIcon(:), etc are? In other words, can you post a code sample that compiles when pasted into a new project?

Comment: import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: SacendPage()){
                    Text("Main Page")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Main Page")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me : have an `@State` property on your first view, that determines whether or not you can show the navigation bar.  Then pass that property on to all subsequent views via `@Binding`, so that it is the 'single source of truth' for whether or not the navigation bar should show.

```
@State private var navBarHidden = false
```

Then on your main view, reference that property for the `navBarHidden` property, and set the title.  Also add an onAppear closure, which will set that hidden property for when this view re-appears, ie if we pop back here from a detail view.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: DetailView(navBarHidden: self.$navBarHidden)
        ) {
            Text("Go to detail view")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(self.navBarHidden)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        self.navBarHidden = true
    })
}
```

Then on a subsequent detail view, pass that navBarHidden property on as an `@Binding` (its passed in above)

```
@Binding var navBarHidden : Bool

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello Detail View!")
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
        .onAppear() {
            self.navBarHidden = false
        }

}
```

And when the `onAppear()` is called above in the detail view, it sets that original property to false for hidden, which shows the nav bar.  And when you click back to return to the home view, the `onAppear()` of the home view is called again, which sets it back to hidden = true.

Comment: is this solution still working? I have a similar issue, the nav bar is not hidden while the push transition is in progress. My nav bar is hidden on both main and details, but for some reason is shown during the transition. I tried hiding the back button and title, however I still have a UI shift upwards after the transition finishes.

Comment: It should still work.  Keep the bool for hidden on the first View, and set it as above in onAppear on that view.  If you dont need to show the navbar between the two views, then you shouldnt have to do anything.  But if you want to set it later, then pass it in to the (sub)view using @Binding as above

Comment: @Emil this is the problem I'm having. I actually want the nav bar on the subsequent views. It's shown during transition, then disappears (on sim. On device, it disappears and pops the view I just pushed. ARGGHHH).

Comment: I've been searching for two days for an answer and this solution works! Has anyone figured out just WHY some navigation links pass on the nav bar being hidden, while others don't? This seems to be totally arbitrary in my case, and can even be corrected (sometimes) by adding a timer to loading certain Combine functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering because I think the solution nowadays is pretty easier. So for people having the same problem just add a

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

on your Home() component and you should be fine. This solution works for sure in Swift 5.5, there is to do the onAppear and onDisappear trick of the other answers. It will hide only the navigation bar on the view you specified

Answer (score -1):

It's a little hard to tell based on the code you've posted, but it looks like you are trying to present a view that slides up from the bottom when `showSaveThePlanet` is true, and also show the navigation bar only when that view appears.

This can be accomplished by setting `.navigationBarHidden(!showSaveThePlanet)` anywhere in your `body` property. Note that your code does not use `NavigationLink` anywhere to push a new view onto the `NavigationView` stack, so you would not get a back button. You can add your own button to dismiss the sheet using `.navigationBarItems(leading:)`

Here is a simplified example showing what I mean.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var detailShowing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top)) {
                Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                // A card-like view that is initially offscreen,
                // and slides on when detailShowing == true
                DetailView()
                    .offset(x: 0, y: detailShowing ? 120 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                    .animation(.spring())

                // Just here to change state
                Button("Toggle") {
                        self.detailShowing.toggle()
                }
                .padding()
                .offset(x: 0, y: detailShowing ? 0 : 44)
                .animation(.none)
            }
            // This is the key modifier
            .navigationBarHidden(!detailShowing)
            .navigationBarTitle("Detail View", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Close") {
                self.detailShowing = false
            })
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top)) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color.secondary).frame(width: 300, height: 500)
            Text("Detail Content")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way that I found is toggling the navBarHidden in destination views. This way incomplete swipe to pop gestures will not remove the navigation bar.

So in your main view you would write

```
@State private var navBarHidden = true

var body: some View {
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(
        destination: DetailView(navBarHidden: self.$navBarHidden)
    ) {
        Text("Go to detail view")
    }
}
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(self.navBarHidden)
}
```

And in your destination view:

```
@Binding var navBarHidden : Bool
var body: some View {
Text("Hello Detail View!")
    .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
    .onAppear {
        self.navBarHidden = false
    }
    .onDisappear {
        self.navBarHidden = true
    }
}
```